# Bitlocker corrupted my drive or?

Tags: windows-8, bitlocker

I just encrypted my drive yesterday with Bitlocker. Everything seemed to go fine and later in the night well after the process was over, I shut my computer down and went to sleep. When I booted my computer again this morning, I can't seem to access my drive again. It asks me for a password which I provide, and then it seems to think it is unlocked. It doesn't give me any errors while unlocking. After that when I try to access the drive I get an error saying "G:\ is not accessible. The disk structure is corrupted and unreadable". I am using Windows 8 x64. I highly regret bitlocking my drive now ...

I have a feeling the partition table could be corrupted or perhaps the encryption corrupted something.

Is there a way to access the drive again or are my drive contents lost for good ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Could you edit your post to contain a question? Also, I would suggest ***always*** backing up your computer before trying anything like this.

Comment: Thanks. I just edited my post. I should have backed up my data, you are correct... sigh.

Comment: I have never used Bitlocker myself, but I imagine this is what would happen if you enter incorrect password.

Comment: I don't believe that's the case since it allows me to change the password after I enter the old password, so it must be correct.